# SSIS Data Flow Task from a PostgreSQL Server to a Oracle DB too slow using Ado Net

Tags: database, postgresql, oracle, ssis

I am using SSIS to load around 100 tables and some oh them have around 30M rows, from a PostsgreSQL server to a Oracle DB. Im using a Data Flow Task from an ADO NET Source to a ADO NET Destination. And they are taking too much time to finish (around 18 hours to a 31M rows table).

Right now my DefaultBufferMaxRows is setup at 1000, and DefaultBufferSize at default 10485760, and my AutoAdjustBufferSize is setup at False.

I tried to change the DefaultBufferMaxRows and the DeffaultBufferSize, the pooling settings and nothing seems to work well.

Comment: Why don't you try OLEDB source & OLEDB destination components? Mostly, they are the ones used with SSIS.

Comment: How can i create and oledb connection manager to the Postgre server?